# module 'fontforge' has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, fonts, fontforge

I'm extracting the glyphs by fontforge:

```py
import fontforge
F = fontforge.open("../{fontAddr}")
for name in F:
    filename = name + ".png"
    F[name].export(filename, {pixelSize})
```

But I get an error:

> 'fontforge' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: Why did you expect that `fontforge.open` exists?

Answer (score 0):

[`fontforge.open`](https://fontforge.org/docs/scripting/python/fontforge.html#fontforge.open) does exist in the FontForge Python API, and it works fine on my machine.

I believe that you have another module somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH` which is named `fontforge.py`. This must be a module resolution error.